# Using custon queue to throw Jquery events in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of animation to do, among other stuff between events..., I would like to know if it if possible to use a custom queue for that. I know I could use other stuff like setTimeout or using callback...but a queue would be handy so I could use it through out functions and not mess the animations (for curiosity to..)

I was thinking something like:

```
$("#content")
.queue("cont_queue", function() {
    $("#backgroung").animate({
        width : "85.6%"
    },900);
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    $("#elem1").fadeIn(900);
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    do order stuf
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    $("#elem2").fadeIn(900);
})
.dequeue("cont_queue").delay(1000, "cont_queue")
.dequeue("cont_queue").delay(1000, "cont_queue")
.dequeue("cont_queue").delay(100, "cont_queue")
.dequeue("cont_queue").delay(1200, "cont_queue");
```

Thanks =)

Comment: If you're not determined to write your own, you might look into Greensock's Javascript API.  They ported their Flash animation library to Javascript and have the notion of a timeline could help you line up your actions. http://www.greensock.com/tag/javascript/.  You might also look into a Javascript async helper (like https://github.com/caolan/async) which could be used to build the queue (instead of callbacks in callbacks in callbacks...).

Comment: Thanks for your help. U got what I need... but still, I would like to know why the above dont work. I mean, if the function is in a custom queue it should not be executed till I "dequeue" it. So without the delay it should behave just like it would normally (async), but with the delay it should not... (it is more like a curiosity)

Comment: You're right.  If the custom queue you are using acts like a queue, it appears that this code should work just fine.  Without seeing the code for the queue, it's hard to figure out exactly what is going on and why things aren't working.  Can you not get into the custom queue code and track it to see if there are issues in there?

Comment: All the queue function does, is it forms an array of functions to call one after the other. It...by itself doesnt call anything.

It returns an array like this 
[function, function, function]

its up to you to go over this array one by one and call the functions

Comment: but calling the functions is what .dequeue("cont_queue") does. isn't it?

Comment: mr rogers: the code executes everything, but the animations do not wait the one before to finish, they just happen. I even tried to put a delay lager than the animation duration, but it was useless.

Comment: Yes, dequeue will do the calling, but you should also pass in the element and in queue functions call the next function (). ill update my answer with a code that works here on stack overflow, if you run it in a console.

Comment: thanks. it something like this. but still, same problem. In your example the cont. element is the only one doing something. and in that case my code also works, but I have several elements.

Comment: can you turn your example into a fiddle

Comment: I made another example like this.
The nr of elements you use is up to you. 
Inside the functions you can select and manipulate whatever you want

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/CTe2F/3/

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, it worked. I just put the timeouts like you did on my code... but still weird they be necessary...I guess the problem is something related to the delay function

Comment: The delay doesnt do anything except its a shorthand version of animation2 in my example below. It adds a setTimeout function into the queue, after the function you called before.
so if you have a queue like 
fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn() then the delay adds a third function into the queue functions list which would then be
[fadeOut, setTimeout, fadeIn], and fade in gets called after setTimeout is done. which gives you the delay effect

Comment: I made a summary down there if anybody need it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//you can use the animation complete parameter in jquery animate.

```
$("something").animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ], function() {
    //first animation is done
    $("somethingElse").animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ], function() {
        //second animation is done and so on
    });
} )


//another option
var cont = $(".container");

animation1 = function(next) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cont.css("background-color","black");
        if (next) {next();}
    }, 2000);
}
animation2 = function(next) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cont.css("background-color","white");
        if (next) {next();}
    }, 2000);
}
jQuery.queue(cont,"animations",animation1);
jQuery.queue(cont,"animations",animation2);
jQuery.queue(cont,"animations",animation1);
jQuery.queue(cont,"animations",animation2);

jQuery.dequeue(cont, "animations");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/CTe2F/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that would do it, but I was trying to avoid callbacks, and also I would like to know why the one I did dont work... in my mind it should (probably I dont understand exactly how the queues work)

Comment: You cant avoid callbacks, since javascript is asynchronous and in the end, you will use callbacks. The difference is that the callbacks are "hidden" from you.

you can also check this for more info.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

Comment: sorry, I express myself badly, I just want to avoid in this case her - for this peace of code. Especially because if I could use a queue it would be pretty handy on the program I am coding - because other functions will put elements in the queue, and it would be good if it was different from fx.

Comment: it is not quite what I was looking for, but works... I just put the "setTimeout" on my version..but can figure out why the delays werent working..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#conteudo")
.queue("cont_queue", function() {
    $("#backgroung").animate({
        width : "85.6%"
    },900);
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("#painel_subsistemas").fadeIn(900);}, 950);
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    carregaTopicos(sistema);
}).queue("cont_queue", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("#topicos_lista").fadeIn(900);}, 950);
});

$("#conteudo").dequeue("cont_queue");
$("#conteudo").dequeue("cont_queue");
$("#conteudo").dequeue("cont_queue");
$("#conteudo").dequeue("cont_queue");
```

Comment: Summary (if anybody need it):
by queuing stuff, you will have a queue with any thing you put there for later (using dequeue function). However, when other elementes are involved, suppose you queue a function with a different element moving , that movement will go for that element's queue and the overall behavior will be just like (async). the delay function will not help, as it is also put in the original queue, it will be called as a settimeout but the other efects will happen ate the same time. to fix that you need to settimeouts for the movements other elements should make to gain control.